# duck typing in D

Tags: metaprogramming, d, duck-typing

I'm new to D, and I was wondering whether it's possible to conveniently do compile-time-checked duck typing.

For instance, I'd like to define a set of methods, and require that those methods be defined for the type that's being passed into a function. It's slightly different from `interface` in D because I wouldn't have to declare that "type X implements interface Y" anywhere - the methods would just be found, or compilation would fail. Also, it would be good to allow this to happen on any type, not just structs and classes. The only resource I could find was [this email thread](http://www.digitalmars.com/d/archives/digitalmars/D/learn/Duck_typing_and_safety._21209.html), which suggests that the following approach would be a decent way to do this:

```
void process(T)(T s)
    if( __traits(hasMember, T, "shittyNameThatProbablyGetsRefactored"))
    // and presumably something to check the signature of that method
{
    writeln("normal processing");
}
```

... and suggests that you could make it into a library call Implements so that the following would be possible:

```
struct Interface {
    bool foo(int, float);
    static void boo(float);
    ...
}

static assert (Implements!(S, Interface));
struct S {
    bool foo(int i, float f) { ... }
    static void boo(float f) { ... }
    ...
}

void process(T)(T s) if (Implements!(T, Interface)) { ... }
```

Is is possible to do this for functions which are not defined in a class or struct? Are there other/new ways to do it? Has anything similar been done?

Obviously, this set of constraints is similar to Go's type system. I'm not trying to start any flame wars - I'm just using D in a way that Go would also work well for.

Comment: Are you trying to make a single function to handle all use cases? I think this would require [static foreach](http://d.puremagic.com/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=4085), but I'm not sure. Maybe some CTFE magic would work? Also of interest: http://www.digitalmars.com/d/archives/digitalmars/D/static_foreach_108369.html

Comment: @tjameson Yes, I believe for the example above you would have to loop through whatever methods are defined in your `Interface` struct at compile time. However, I'm also open to other ways of achieving the same goal if they exist.

Comment: D has wrap and unwrap (http://dlang.org/phobos-prerelease/std_typecons.html#.wrap and http://dlang.org/phobos-prerelease/std_typecons.html#.unwrap) provide feature similar to Go's duck typing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is actually a very common thing to do in D. It's how ranges work. For instance, the most basic type of range - the input range - must have 3 functions:

```
bool empty();  //Whether the range is empty
T front();  // Get the first element in the range
void popFront();  //pop the first element off of the range
```

Templated functions then use [`std.range.isInputRange`](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_range.html#isInputRange) to check whether a type is a valid range. For instance, the most basic overload of [`std.algorithm.find`](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_algorithm.html#find) looks like

```
R find(alias pred = "a == b", R, E)(R haystack, E needle)
if (isInputRange!R &&
    is(typeof(binaryFun!pred(haystack.front, needle)) : bool))
{ ... }
```

`isInputRange!R` is `true` if `R` is a valid input range, and `is(typeof(binaryFun!pred(haystack.front, needle)) : bool)` is `true` if `pred` accepts `haystack.front` and `needle` and returns a type which is implicitly convertible to `bool`. So, this overload is based entirely on static duck typing.

As for `isInputRange` itself, it looks something like

```
template isInputRange(R)
{
    enum bool isInputRange = is(typeof(
    {
        R r = void;       // can define a range object
        if (r.empty) {}   // can test for empty
        r.popFront();     // can invoke popFront()
        auto h = r.front; // can get the front of the range
    }));
}
```

It's an eponymous template, so when it's used, it gets replaced with the symbol with its name, which in this case is an enum of type `bool`. And that `bool` is `true` if the type of the expression is non-`void`. `typeof(x)` results in `void` if the expression is invalid; otherwise, it's the type of the expression `x`. And `is(y)` results in `true` if `y` is non-`void`. So, `isInputRange` will end up being `true` if the code in the `typeof` expression compiles, and `false` otherwise.

The expression in `isInputRange` verifies that you can declare a variable of type `R`, that `R` has a member  (be it a function, variable, or whatever) named `empty` which can be used in a condition, that `R` has a function named `popFront` which takes no arguments, and that `R` has a member `front` which returns a value. This is the API expected of an input range, and the expression inside of `typeof` will compile if `R` follows that API, and therefore, `isInputRange` will be `true` for that type. Otherwise, it will be `false`.

D's standard library has quite a few such eponymous templates (typically called traits) and makes heavy use of them in its template constraints. [`std.traits`](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_traits.html) in particular has quite a few of them. So, if you want more examples of how such traits are written, you can look in there (though some of them are fairly complicated). The internals of such traits are not always particularly pretty, but they do encapsulate the duck typing tests nicely so that template constraints are much cleaner and more understandable (they'd be much, much uglier if such tests were inserted in them directly).

So, that's the normal approach for static duck typing in D. It does take a bit of practice to figure out how to write them well, but that's the standard way to do it, and it works. There have been people who have suggested trying to come up with something similar to your `Implements!(S, Interface)` suggestion, but nothing has really come of that of yet, and such an approach would actually be less flexible, making it ill-suited for a lot of traits (though it could certainly be made to work with basic ones). Regardless, the approach that I've described here is currently the standard way to do it.

Also, if you don't know much about ranges, I'd suggest reading [this](http://ddili.org/ders/d.en/ranges.html).

Comment: It is actually one of most simple and at the same time inconvenient things about meta-programming in D. There is no problem in implementing "Implements" (see my answer) but to be really useful, it needs to be supported via native syntax template tmpl(T : DuckTypeInterface). A bit more flexible that isXRange, but so much more readable and so much better error messages. Don't think we can expect something like that soon though.

Answer (score 2):

Implements!(S, Interface) is possible but did not get enough attention to get into standard library or get better language support. Probably if I won't be the only one telling it is the way to go for duck typing, we will have a chance to have it :)

Proof of concept implementation to tinker around:

http://dpaste.1azy.net/6d8f2dc4

```
import std.traits;

bool Implements(T, Interface)()
    if (is(Interface == interface))
{
    foreach (method; __traits(allMembers, Interface))
    {
        foreach (compareTo; MemberFunctionsTuple!(Interface, method)) 
        {
            bool found = false;

            static if ( !hasMember!(T, method) )
            {
                pragma(msg, T, " has no member ", method);
                return false;
            }
            else
            {               
                foreach (compareWhat; __traits(getOverloads, T, method))
                {
                    if (is(typeof(compareTo) == typeof(compareWhat)))
                    {
                        found = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (!found)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}

interface Test
{
    bool foo(int, double);
    void boo();
}

struct Tested
{
    bool foo(int, double);
//  void boo();
}

pragma(msg, Implements!(Tested, Test)());

void main()
{
}
```